# Why do my NDI Sources not appear in Windows (or OBS on Windows)

Tags: obs

I noticed recently that even when on a 'known good' configuration of computer and network, NDI sources could not be found even by NDI Studio Monitor or by the OBS plugins that provide NDI sources.

This problems appears to be intermittent in nature, often going away after various investigations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some diagnostics we eventually determined this to be caused by a strange issue in windows where if you switch between Wireless networks then mDNS starts to misbehave. (Helped, enormously, by this thread: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101168/mdns-not-sending-queries-to-the-network.html)

To fix the issue, you can simply disable the wireless interface, then re-enable it. This is not the same as 'turning off your wifi'. You must do this disable through the Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections screen.

If you restart the NDI Studio Monitor you should now see all your missing sources!